# How to pack prerelease nuget packages through Azure DevOps (yml)?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I was trying to set the package version using the following `yml`, however I keep getting the error
`##[error]No value was found for the provided environment variable.` when the dotnetcli task is executed.

```yml
trigger:
- master

name: 0.1.2-prerelease.$(Date:yyMM)$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:rr)

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  nugetVersion: 0.1.2-prerelease.$(Date:yyMM)$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:rr)

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versionEnvVar: '$(nugetVersion)'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to pack prerelease nuget packages through Azure DevOps (yml)?

There are couple of alternatives

#### 1

If you want use the `$(Date:yyMM)$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:rr)` in the nuget version, the directly way to achieve this is using `byBuildNumber`.

#### 2

using $(build.BuildNumber) as mentioned by `Shayki Abramczyk`

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versionEnvVar: '$(build.BuildNumber)'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
```

#### 3

But if the `byBuildNumber`  is not your choice, **we need to create our own `$(Date:yyMM)` and `$(Rev:rr)`**. That because those `$(Date:yyMM)` and `$(Rev:rr)` variables could not be parsed in the Variables.

You could check my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421021/nuget-packager-with-version-using-build-number-adding-beta/57425348#57425348) for the details info.

To create the `$(Date:yyMM)`, we could parse the date of the `pipeline.startTime` to get the value of `$(Date:yyMM)$(DayOfMonth)`：

```
variables:
  date: '$[format('{0:yyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime)]'
```

Then we create the `$(Rev:rr)`, we could use a counter, like:

```
variables:
  InternalNumber: '1'
  CounterNumber: '$[counter(variables['InternalNumber'], 1)]'
```

Now, the variable of `nugetVersion` could be:

```
variables:
  date: '$[format('{0:yyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime)]'
  InternalNumber: '1'
  CounterNumber: '$[counter(variables['InternalNumber'], 1)]'
  nugetVersion: '0.1.2-prerelease.$(date)$(CounterNumber)'
```

As the test result:

[image]

Comment: byBuildNumber can't seems to take `prerelease` etc text, and ignores it. If that is true, you should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you specified `byEnvVar` you just need to give the variable **name**, when you put it with `$()` you give the variable **value** and not the **name**.

So, just change it to:

```
versionEnvVar: 'nugetVersion'
```

Comment: I tried that too, I get the compilation error `error MSB4018: The "GetPackOutputItemsTask" task failed unexpectedly.  error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: PackageVersion string specified '0.1.2-prerelease.$(Date:yyMM)$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:rr)' is invalid. `

Comment: in the `nugetVersion` variable put the value: `$(build.buildnumber)` (the `name`)

Comment: BTW - if the `nugetVersion` should be like the `name` you can give him `byBuildNumber` instead of `byEnvVar`

Comment: Yesterday I tried `$(build.buildnumber)`, it works. However, `byBuildNumber` did not i think that was failing silently.

Comment: Thanks so much! For others struggling, here's my full solution I used to get it working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718866/azure-pipeline-nuget-package-versioning-scheme-how-to-get-1-0-revr#71241200